# Difference between generate and append when querying and adding data to array?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
var objectarray = [PFObject]()

func populateTable() {

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in

        self.objectarray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.searchTableView.reloadData()

        if error == nil {
```

Above is the query I am doing and the below 2 codes are what I can use to use the query to populate a array.

```
                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                    self.objectarray = Array(objects.generate())

                }
```

Is there any difference with running this code above to populate my array or running the code below?

```
for object in objects! {

                        self.objectarray.append(object)

}
```

Doing either works to load onto my tableView. Also another question regarding Parse. After doing the above, the user doesn't download PFFiles from the background until I run

```
getDataInBackgroundWithBlock
```

right? I want to know if it'd be beneficial to save smaller versions of images onto the server.

Comment: Correct on the second part about `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`. You'll have to download the data and then set it into a `UIImage`.